# How to fetch content of Book created in Moodle using APIs?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

How to fetch content of Book created in Moodle using APIs?

I have tested mod_book_view_book function, but I am only getting book name, not the content of book.

Answer (score 1):

Use core_course_get_contents function, then take from response elements, where modname="book"

Example:

```
https://host/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=user_token&wsfunction=core_course_get_contents&moodlewsrestformat=json&courseid=31
```